# Dividing an array of n integers > 0 into M continuous sub-sequences so that the maximal sum of some partition is minimal

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

First of all I must mention I've seen some solutions on this site that didn't work when I checked them or do not match my question since I want to do it in a dynamic programming way.

I've tried all things but I'm really lost, I need to partition the given sequence of natural numbers into M continuous sub-sequences so that the maximal sum of some partition is minimal.

For example: {4,8,7,10,40,15,30,2,1,20} and M = 4
The algorithm should generate {4,8,7,10}{40}{15,30}{2,1,20} because now the maximum sum is 15 + 30 = 45. Again, I mention that I've seen a post on this site which didn't work.

Comment: Are there negative numbers?

Comment: Only positive numbers

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward dynamic programming solutions:

1. The state is `(i, j)`, where `i` is the last element of the current partition and `j` is the number of parts there're in partition.
2. The value of the state is the maximum sum so far.
3. The transitions are `max(f(i, j), sum(i + 1, k)) -> f(k, j + 1)` (it means that we take the `[i + 1, k]` part).
4. The answer is `f(N, M)` (it means that we took `N` elements and created exactly `M` groups).

Answer (score 0):

The maximum sum partition can be found by taking the entire sequence and cutting off `M-1` one-element partitions on either side. You should do this in a way such that the sum of cut-off elements is minimal.

This gives you a single integer degree of freedom (the number of elements to cut off from the beginning). So you can just iterate this number from `0` thru `M - 1` (the number of elements to cut off from the end is then obviously `M - 1 - i`) and take the minimum.

In your example, this would result in:

```
{4}, {8}, {7}, {10, 40, 15, 30, 2, 1, 20}
```

The maximum sum of any partition is then 118.

Comment: (This answers [revision 1 of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40947531/1), if somewhat cheekily.)